# Do Brits use 'inquire' or 'enquire'?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Do British people use ”inquire” or ”enquire”?

I just read it’s more common in AmE, is that true?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the general expectations of Stack Exchangeg is that you demonstrate your initial efforts at research. For example, you might check dictionaries to see if there are notes about regional usage, or search for either in British or American publications. Please [edit[ your post to include such information. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Google Ngram is your friend.*https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) and use the search term - **inquire: eng_gb_2012,enquire: eng_gb_2012, inquire: eng_us_2012, enquire: eng_us_2012**